# Apache 2 instalation / Ubuntu 13.04 - Package not found

Tags: apache, installation-package, ubuntu-13.04

No matter what I do I cannot get the package installed :
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install apache2
..though my computer is telling me ...

The program 'apache2' can be found in the following packages:
 * apache2-mpm-event
 * apache2-mpm-prefork
 * apache2-mpm-worker
 * apache2-mpm-itk
Try: sudo apt-get install

When I do this ... for instance with 
root@xxxx:/home/fakler# apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apache2-mpm-prefork

pt-get update shows me many  errors  like that ...

Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

Tried also  installing Apache from here :
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/apache2.2-common/

but hitting click on the button available on the Software centre does not wor either (Nothing happens).

Someone has an  idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could figure it out myself. Somewhere in Ubuntu, forgotten where, I just found it, there is an option where You can allow the user - Yourself - what are the reliable ressources for software upgrade/download. I did confirm that I allow download from the official Ubuntu ressources/servers as well as canonical software, third party software etc. I did also allow access / updates/installs from my CD Rom drive. After that, I could do the Apache 2 installation.